# Inconvenientes a la hora de abrir un chat de WhatsApp C#

Tags: c#, windows, whatsapp

Estimadxs, buenas tardes tengan, acudo aquí porque es algo que no he podido solucionar y me llama bastante la atención. Tengo una aplicación hecha en `C#` la cual se encarga de recoger un número de teléfono desde la `BD` y, mediante un botón, abrir el chat del mismo.
Cabe remarcar que la versión de `WhatsApp Desktop` utilizada para esto es la `2.2244.6`. La semana pasada, instalé desde la `Microsoft Store` la última versión de WhatsApp que es la versión `2.2245.5.0`, así que yendo por partes muestro cómo hago lo que necesito y las fallas que tengo. Lo primero que hago, para iniciar el chat con el número obtenido desde la `BD`, es crear el siguiente proceso y usarlo en el botón:

```
var process = $"whatsapp://send?phone=5435111223344&text=hola!";
Process.Start(process);
```

Esto hasta hace dos semanas, en la `versión 2.2244.6` funcionaba bien, me abría el chat con el mensaje en el número ingresado. Pero, ahora, no me abre los chats. Me figura el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Distinto con la `versión 2.2245.5.0`, en esta me abre el chat pero no me muestra el mensaje.

Analizando posibilidades, pensé en la de agregar el número nueve luego del prefijo, quedando algo como:

```
var process = $"whatsapp://send?phone=54935111223344&text=hola!";
```

Esto supuso lo siguiente: de cinco números de teléfono, solo uno me abrió el chat. El resto me mostró el mensaje de error que se ve en la imagen anterior. `(Versión 2.2244.6)`

En la versión `2.2245.5.0`, sigue abriendo el chat pero sin el texto.

Realizando otro análisis, probé usando el `wa.me/` en el navegador de `Chrome`. El resultado es el mismo, en la versión `2.2244.6` muestra el error y en la versión `2.2245.5.0` me abre el chat pero me abre el chat sin el texto. Quiero aclarar que, si agendo el número de teléfono en el celular, cuando presiono el botón en mi aplicación de C# me abre el chat en ambas versiones. Solo que, persistentemente, en la `2.2245.5.0` no me muestra el texto que quiero enviar.

Entonces, mi consulta/duda es, ¿Cómo puedo solucionar el inconveniente para que funcione en cualquiera de las dos versiones?

Comment: Utiliza formato internacional para los números de teléfono.

Comment: El formato internacional es 54 (Argentina). Todos los números que hay en la BD son de Argentina. @fredyfx

Comment: `+54` en lugar de `54`, quizás funciona :)

Comment: Eso tampoco lo soluciona @fredyfx

Comment: Al menos se intentó. :D

Comment: gracias por tu tiempo invertido @fredyfx Xd

Comment: Claro :D Al menos, ahora ya sabrán que hubo un intento.

Comment: Buenas, he encontrado en la página web una forma d'enviar el WhatsApp el mensaje se aparece, pero parece que falta enviar un intro, ya que lo carga a la barra de mensajes, pero no lo envía.

Link: https://faq.whatsapp.com/452366545421244/?locale=es_LA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El [FAQ](https://faq.whatsapp.com/425247423114725/?cms_platform=iphone&locale=es_LA) de Whastapp (para iPhone) te muestra cómo crear un **Esquema de URL personalizada**

---

Acá se muestran algunos ejemplos de uso de la API de Whatsapp, la cual es tu mejor apuesta. Puedes usar:

`https://wa.me/{tu numero}?text={tu texto}` que te redirigirá hacia `https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone={tu numero}&text={tu texto}&type=phone_number&app_absent=0`

Donde:

`phone` es el número de Whstapp con el que deseas abrir la conversación

`text` es el texto inicial que aparecerá al abrir la conversación

`type` no estoy seguro, especifica que se trata de un número telefónico?

`app_absent` especifica si la app de Whatsapp está ausente o no

---

Y ya con esta información, podrías construir un método de conveniencia.

```
private static void OpenWhatsappChat(string phone, string text)
{
    string whatsappLink = $"https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone={phone}&text={text}&type=phone_number&app_absent=0";
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(whatsappLink);
}
```

Entonces

```
OpenWhatsappChat("5435111223344", "hola!");
```

---

Probado en

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hasta ahora, todo bien. No tengo mi pc para probarlo, cuando lo probaste, al abrirte la app de WhatsApp para Windows, ¿En la caja de texto figuraba el "hola!"?

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo Sí, precisamente me percaté de que reportaste que no te aparecía el texto, así que probé con diferentes textos, incluido 'Hola!' y me salió en la casilla al abrir la conversación. Prueba a pegar `https://wa.me/5435111223344?text=Hola!` en la barra de direcciones de tu navegador y pulsar Enter, a mí me funcionó (obviamente con un número existente en mis contactos, no probé con el que usas para pruebas)

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo ¿Te funcionó?

Comment: No he podido probarlo pues la pc, esta en mi trabajo y he estado enfermo xd mañana vuelvo por lo que temprano te podré comentar si me funciona o no

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo Excelente, me alegra saber que te funcionó ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Capaz este sea el error:

1. Enviar el prefijo con el simbolo +
2. El + convertir en **cod hexadecimal (%2B)** para que interprete la URL.

Estuve probando en wa.me y la url que me funciona para que abra el chat con el mensaje seria este:

https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=%2B595974225570&text&type=phone_number&app_absent=0

Con el numero que proveíste de ejemplo no funciona, revisa que el número no haya sido bloqueado por WhatsApp y que eventualmente exista ese numero en WhatsApp ya que si ese numero no tiene whatsapp suele dar ese error.

Lo otro seria probar otro método de concatenación para generar tu URL, capaz en la nueva versión no le esta gustando jaja

Comment: Añadir el símbolo + solo fue una recomendación qué probé. El número proporcionado en la pregunta, es falso. Es solo un número de ejemplo debido a que no expondré ni mi número ni el número de otra persona públicamente. Y otro tema, es que si bien me recomiendas esa url (que si bien me abre la aplicación) en tu `&text` no le añades el texto. Para probar, lo modifiqué quedando así:  `&text=hola` y el resto de la url. Eso si bien sigue abriendo el chat, no pone el texto. Y como digo en la pregunta, en la última versión de WhatsApp puedo abrir el chat pero no carga el texto.